# What steps do I take to transfer a WordPress site from one host to another?

Tags: domains, web-hosting, wordpress

I have a self-hosted WordPress site at a hosting provider but I need to move it to a new hosting company.

How do I transfer my WordPress installation from one host to the other, and then how do I re-point my domain name to the new host?

In what order do I do these things to minimize the downtime?

Comment: I second that. Can you please edit this question to be clearer as to what you are asking? We love to help people here and the participants of this site are excellent.

Comment: @user3614715 - I rephrased your first sentence. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: @closetnoc im already edit it :) Hope you undestand what im asking about :(

Comment: @dartonw hi thanks for rephrased my question, but im asking to clear all my data and content not to transfer the data and content to another servers :) Thanks to you again :)

Comment: Presumably you're asking about migrating to a new web hosting provider rather than ISP (the provider of your internet service)?

Comment: @zigojacko Lots of helpful edits towards getting this reopened - it appears "hosting" was originally used instead of "ISP".

Comment: @dan - Despite the edits then, the question still appears to be unclear (or maybe that's just me).

Comment: @zigojacko It's gone through some different permutations, but should be clearer now, and hopefully what the original poster intended.

Comment: Looks much better @dan :)

Comment: It's always good to see edits and comments as in this case to help get questions back open (which is my preference).

Answer (score 1):

1) Make a dump (backup) of your database.

2) FTP the code from your current host to your new host.

3) Create a database on your new host. Make certain that the database name and username is the same as it is on the current platform. If this is not possible, then you'll need to modify your code to suit the new platform.

4) Execute the SQL script created in step 1 to restore your database.

5) Your new host should provide you with a temporary URL that you can use for testing. Test the site *thoroughly.*

6) After thoroughly testing the site, login to the domain registrar and change your name servers (DNS). 
*NB: Don't forget to consider email (if applicable).